# Tengo un Problema cuando le doy a Mi Boton Guardar o Insertar de mi formulario , ya que no me guarda ni me presenta ningún error, no se que hacer

Tags: c#, mysql

Este en la Orden que le estoy dando a mi botón guardar ,para que me guarde los datos en mi base de datos llamada Paciente.
no encuentro el cual es la razón , cuando le doy click al botón no me hace nada, es como si no recibiera la orden.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Consultorio_Clinico
{
    public partial class Pacientes : Form
    {
        public Pacientes()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        MySqlConnection conectarp = new MySqlConnection("server=localHost;DataBase=xxxx;Uid=*****;pwd=****;");
        DataSet ds;
        MySqlDataReader ddd;
        MySqlCommand comandoX;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Paciente_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PopulateX();
        }

        public void PopulateX()
        {
            string selecionado = "SELECT * FROM paciente ";
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter mostrar = new MySqlDataAdapter(selecionado, conectarp);
            mostrar.Fill(table);
            dtgpaciente.DataSource = table;
            }

        private void btnguardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
            try
            {
                string insertarX = "insert into paciente(id_pacient,nom_pacient,ed_pacient,tel_pacient,dir_pacient,ciud_pacient,sex_pacient) values ('" + txtidpacient.Text + "','" + txtnompacient.Text + "','" + txtedapacient.Text + "','" + txttelpacient.Text + "','" + txtdirpacient.Text + "','" + txtciudpacient.Text + "','" + txtsexopacient.Text + "')";
                EjecutarMyConsultaP(insertarX);
                PopulateX();


                MessageBox.Show("Registro guardado con exito");
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error.." + error.Message);
                conectarp.Close();
                txtidpacient.Clear();
                txtnompacient.Clear();
                txtedapacient.Clear();
                txttelpacient.Clear();
                txtdirpacient.Clear();
                txtciudpacient.Clear();
                txtsexopacient.Clear();

            }

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }

        private void dtgpaciente_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dtgpaciente_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            txtidpacient.Text = dtgpaciente.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            txtnompacient.Text = dtgpaciente.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            txtedapacient.Text = dtgpaciente.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            txttelpacient.Text = dtgpaciente.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            txtdirpacient.Text = dtgpaciente.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            txtciudpacient.Text = dtgpaciente.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            txtsexopacient.Text = dtgpaciente.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        }

        public void Abrirconetion()
        {
            if (conectarp.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conectarp.Open();
            }
        }

        public void Cerrarconetion()
        {
            if (conectarp.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conectarp.Close();
            }
        }
        public void EjecutarMyConsultaP(string ConsultaP)
        {
            try
            {
                Abrirconetion();
                comandoX = new MySqlCommand(ConsultaP,conectarp);
            }
            catch (Exception executeP)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(executeP.Message);

                if (comandoX.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                { 
                MessageBox.Show ("Consulta Ejecutada");
                }
                else
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Consulta No Ejecutada");
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Cerrarconetion();
            }
        }

        private void btnacertar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string inserQuery = "INSERT INTO paciente (id_pacient,nom_pacient,ed_pacient,tel_pacient,dir_pacient,ciud_pacient,sex_pacien VALUES ('" + txtidpacient + "','" + txtnompacient.Text + "','" + txtedapacient.Text + "','" + txtedapacient.Text + "','" + txttelpacient.Text + "','" + txtdirpacient.Text + "','" + txtciudpacient.Text + "','" + txtsexopacient.Text + "')";
            EjecutarMyConsultaP(inserQuery);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Nataniel, el error debe estar en `EjecutarMyConsultaP()` y/o en `PopulateX()`. Por favor coloca el código de ambos métodos para poder encontrar el error. Por otro lado te recomiendo utilzar consultas parametrizadas, de lo contrario el query que tienes actualmente es suceptible a ataques de [Inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL)

Comment: Aparece el mensaje de error o el de registro guardado con exito?

Comment: de paso, Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: ahii esta todo mi codigo de ese formulario, espero que me ayuden

Comment: @gbiachi no me aparece ningun mensaje de error

Answer (score 5):

Viendo el código, tu ejecución del comando MySql esta dentro del `catch` por lo que no se ejecutara hasta que el `try` genere un error, el cual no le veo que vaya a ocurrir nunca, por lo que movemos el bloque **ExecuteNonQuery** a la parte de `try` donde este debe de ejecutar la consulta:

```
public void EjecutarMyConsultaP(string ConsultaP)
{
    try //Se ejecuta primero
    {
        Abrirconetion();
        comandoX = new MySqlCommand(ConsultaP,conectarp);
        if (comandoX.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
         { 
             MessageBox.Show ("Consulta Ejecutada");
         }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Consulta No Ejecutada");
         }
    }
    catch (Exception executeP) //Solo si ocurre un error en la ejecucion caemos en este bloque de codigo
    {
        MessageBox.Show(executeP.Message);   
    }
    finally //Despues de que el try o el catch finalizan su ejecucion se ejecuta el finally
    {
        Cerrarconetion();
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias , Pero ahora me sale un Error

Comment: Actualiza tu pregunta y adjunta el error que te sale, Saludos

Comment: @JesusRodríguez OP ya hizo una nueva pregunta y fue respondida tambien.

Comment: Perfeco gracias por la actualización @gbianchi, Saludos