# SQL syntax error en MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, mysqli

Este es el error que me presenta cuando quiero guardar ahora mis datos , disculpen que no lo aya planteado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿puedes agregar el enlace a tu pregunta de referencia? no leí la pregunta anterior, no sé que te halla pasado antes.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/95631/tengo-un-problema-cuando-le-doy-a-mi-boton-guardar-o-insertar-de-mi-formulario

Comment: por favor acepta la respuesta anterior.. mira todos los links que te pasamos antes..

Comment: revisa mi respuesta, y no dudes en marcarla como respuesta si te es útil (la palomita al lado de la respuesta)

Comment: Pero ese error a mi parecer es que esta intentando meter un varchar a un campo entero.

Answer (score 6):

El error es claro, te dice que tienes un error en tu sintaxis de tu instrucción SQL. estás pasándo el valor `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`, porque, supongo que en tu cadena asignaste el valor del textbox nadamás, tipo:

```
String Sql="Insert into X Values"+TuTextBox;
```

cuando (según recuerdo) debería de ser:

```
String Sql="Insert into X Values"+TuTextBox.Text;
```

*X es referencia a la tabla, y `TuTextBox` es el textbox que te está generando el error.*

Comment: uso mysql de base de datos  en otro formularios que llevan casi la misma cadenas , me tira ese error ..

Comment: puedes anexar una cadena de ejemplo? para que vea que puede ser, pero estoy seguro que debe ser el error que te comenté, basta con que leas detalladamente tu cadena.

Answer (score 0):

El error que te da es por tipo de dato que deseas almacenar en la tabla, lo mas probable es que sea de tipo entero y tu en la sintaxis de sql ingreasas texto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para corregirlo tienes 2 opciones cambiar el tipo de dato en la tabla a texto o simplemenete cargar el texto de tu caja de texto, un ejemplo seria asi:

```
con.Ejecutar_Accion("INSERT INTO `categoria`(`Nivel_Sub`, `Denominacion`, `Area`, `Observacion`) VALUES ('"+txtNivel.Text
            +"','"+txtDenominacion.Text+"','"+CBArea.Text+"','"+RTBObservaciones.Text+"')", "rh", "Error al dar de alta la categoria");
```

Solo tienes que poner el nombre de tu caja de texto mas el punto y la propiedad text:

```
txtDenominacion.Text
```

Comment: Realmente estoy que no entendí Nada , Y disculpa pero es que soy Novato y es un Proyerto que me toca entregar hoy, estoy ya sin ideas de como arreglar eso podrías , cojer como ejeplo los codigos que envien y decirme esto lo pone asi y esto asi por favor

Comment: Nececito ver tu cadena de la sintaxis para enteder mejor el error y corregirlo

Comment: Mira edite La pregunta chequea el codigo

Comment: El campo id_pacient y el campo ed_pacient que tipo de datos son en tu base de datos?